# I need help with my script

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, script

So I have this script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

Mage::app();

/* tell the browser that we are a csv file */
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

/* Set our dates */
$fromDate = '2016-05-20 00:00:00';
$toDate = '2019-01-01 00:00:00';

/* Get the collection. Here we set a date range, and ignore cancelled orders.
   You can filter the collection however you prefer */
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled')));

/* Here you can build an array, print to screen, write to a CSV etc */
echo "Order ID,Customer Name,Order Total".PHP_EOL;
foreach($orders as $o){

    /* lets output the required data in csv format */
    echo $o->getIncrementId().',';
    echo $o->getCustomerName().',';
    echo $o->getBaseGrandTotal();
    echo PHP_EOL;

    /* you can load the order items, if you need them */
    //$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
}
```

I want to get the sku, products ordered, quantity ordered. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to get Product Info. If you want more Information about product the you can load that product inside `foreach` loop.

```
$items = $o->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $i):
    echo $i->getProductId();
     echo $i->getSku();
endforeach;
```

Thanks

Comment: Where can I put that into my code?

Comment: where you comment out line `$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
}`.   Inside Order Loop

Comment: Also how can I separate each?

Comment: Please accept my answer if its useful.

Comment: I haven't been able to use your code.  The output is too messy.